# Java SAX parsing: Can't override DefauldHandler's startElement()

Tags: java, sax

I'm trying to implement a simple SAX parser.

```
public class XmlParser {
    public parseXML(File inputFile) {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser   parser = factory.newSAXParser(); 
            SaxHandler handler = new SaxHandler();
            parser.parse(inputFile, handler);
        } ....
    }

    private static class SaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, 
                             String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) 
                             throws SAXException { 
        }  

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                           String qName) throws SAXException {
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't seem to override the startElement method. When I add @Override, a "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype" message appears. All the other handlers are properly called except for startElement.

Thank you.

Comment: that typically means you have a bad import.

Comment: Please include the imports in your code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm betting you have a bad import for the `Attributes` class, should be [`org.xml.sax.Attributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html).

*always* use [`@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.4), it's designed to protect you from this exact problem.

Comment: Awesome! I did in fact have a bad import (java.util.jar.Attributes). I actually did use Override on all the handler methods, it's just that both Ecliplse and NetBeans kept complaining about the @Override above the startElement giving me an error. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have imported the wrong `DefaultHandler` or `Attributes` class?

Make sure you imported:

```
org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler
org.xml.sax.Attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way, in my opinion, is not write this methodes manually, but using ctrl+space, and select wanted to override methodes from contextual menu (in Eclipse).
Methodes will be generated by IDE automaticaly, including annotation @Override, and in the same time, will be imported necessary packages.